# jQuery add class only to one element

Tags: jquery, wordpress

on my fluent form in wordpress site i want to add class with jQuery to only one span on hover. But if i hover on option jquery add classes to all spans. problem is on step 3 [website](https://calc.ffd.sk/denir/)
i just want to add class only hovered span
i use this script

```
jQuery(".fluentform .ff-el-group.biele .ff-el-form-check.ff-el-image-holder").hover(
  function () {
    jQuery(".fluentform .ff-el-group.biele .ff-el-form-check.ff-el-image-holder label.ff-el-form-check-label span").addClass('active-hover');
  },
  function () {
    jQuery(".fluentform .ff-el-group.biele .ff-el-form-check.ff-el-image-holder label.ff-el-form-check-label span").removeClass("active-hover");
  }
);
```

[image]

Comment: have a try `$(this).find('label.ff-el-form-check-label span').addClass(...)`, `jQuery(".fluentform....` finds all spans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using `jQuery(this)` (referring to the currently hovered element) u should be able to only add the class to the span inside the element

```
jQuery(".fluentform .ff-el-group.biele .ff-el-form-check.ff-el-image-holder").hover(
  function () {
    jQuery(this).find('span').addClass('active-hover');
  },
  function () {
    jQuery(this).find('span').removeClass('active-hover');
  }
);
```

the way u tried `".fluentform .ff-el-group.biele .ff-el-form-check.ff-el-image-holder label.ff-el-form-check-label span"` will match all those spans (length = 8)

Comment: Thanks a lot... it works